# Threading events using GreenRobot EventBus

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

I've just started looking at GreenRobot's [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/) for Android and have a question about threading.

I have a long-running process that I'd like to run on a background thread which, when completed, updates the UI.

So something like:

```
public void onEventBackgroundThread(MyEvent event) {
        doSomeLongRunningProcess();
        updateUI();
    }
```

Obviously `updateUI()` can't be called here because it would also run in the background.

So what would be the recommended way to handle this? Fire another event from within my `onEventBackgroundThread()` which will run on the UI thread? Or fire it from the long-running-process itself? Or is there a better pattern?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would probably fire another event when you get the result.

```
public void onEventBackgroundThread(MyEvent event) {
    doSomeLongRunningProcess();
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new MyEventResult());
}
```

**Be aware though**: [reading the docs](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/delivery-threads-threadmode/), you find this:

> **BackgroundThread**: Subscriber will be called in a background thread. If
>   posting thread is not the main thread, event handler methods will be
>   called directly in the posting thread. If the posting thread is the
>   main thread, **EventBus uses a single background thread that will
>   deliver all its events sequentially**. Event handlers using this mode
>   should try to return quickly to avoid blocking the background thread.

If you take a long time in this method, other EventBus callbacks will be delayed which will probably translate to an unresponsive application.

You probably want to use onEventAsync:

> **Async**: Event handler methods are called in a separate thread. This is
>   always independent from the posting thread and the main thread.
>   Posting events never wait for event handler methods using this mode.
>   Event handler methods should use this mode if their execution might
>   take some time, e.g. for network access. Avoid triggering a large
>   number of long running asynchronous handler methods at the same time
>   to limit the number of concurrent threads. EventBus uses a thread pool
>   to efficiently reuse threads from completed asynchronous event handler
>   notifications.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest firing another event which will be handled by `onEventMainThread` method.

This has a positive impact of the `updateUI` not being called at all if the receiver is already unregistered (e.g. activity unregistered because it was destroyed).